# How can I make this website responsive specifically for mobile screens?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

Can someone help me to make this page responsive?

When the page is shown on a mobile phone the picture of the chicken needs to fill the screen, followed by the picture of the chair and table with text. When you scroll further down you need tot get two columns with picture and text,when you scroll further down ou get 3 columns with picture and text on one screen etc.

Only use html and Css, no javascript or bootstrap.

I tried different kinds of display but I can't get a good result.

Can someone explain me how to set correctly the media query.

I included the css and html code below

Thank you so much

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}




body,
    {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 1614px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.main-header {
    background-image: url(img/bkg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 774px;
    margin-bottom: 52px;
}

.main-header .header-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: 40px;
    color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
}

.main-header .header-content h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
}

.main-header .header-content p {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.bars,
.close {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.bars p,
.close p {
    margin-top: -3px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.menu-plein-ecran {
    background-color: #3b685b;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
}

.menu-plein-ecran:target {
    display: block;
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.navbar li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px;
}

.navbar li a {
    font-size: 4em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar li a:hover {
    color: #f44336;
}

/**************************main**********************/

main {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-content .container1,
.main-content .container2,
.main-content .container3 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(14rem, 1fr));
    grid-column-gap: 50px;

}

.main-content > .more {
    color: #549ff3;
}

.main-content .more:hover {
    color: #f00;
}

.main-content h2 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.main-content p {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

/************************ footer form container***********************/

.form-container {

    padding: 1em;
}

.wrapper2 > * {
    padding: 1em;
}

.contact {
    width: 900px;
    height: 50vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.5);
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.contact h1 {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.contact form {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 20px;
}

.contact form p {
    margin: 0;
}

.contact form label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #669;
}

.contact form button {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 0.5em;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#b9bbde, #669);
}

.contact .full {
    grid-area: 3/1/4/3;
    text-align: center;
}

.contact form input,
.contact form textarea {
    width: 92%;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #c9e6ff;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.contact form button:hover,
.contact form button:focus {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#666, #444);
    outline: 0;
}

footer {
    background-image: url(img/bkg-form.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    margin-top: 50px;
    height: 636px;

}

footer ul {
    background: #ff7fcf;
    margin: 0;
}

footer a {
    border-left: 1em solid #ededed;
    color: #ededed;
    padding-left: .75em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

footer a:hover {
    border-color: #333;
}

footer a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 0.2em;
    margin-left: 1em;
    min-width: 26%;
}

.item:after,
nav:after,
footer ul:after,
.content:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>devoir2</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <!---------------wrapper------------------->
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!--------------- début header------------------->
        <header class="main-header" id="top">
            <div class="bars">
                <p>menu</p>
                <a href="#menu"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="header-content">
                <h1>d-angle</h1>
                <p>a responsive answer</p>
            </div>
            <!---------------navbar------------------->
            <nav class="menu-plein-ecran" id="menu">
                <div class="close">
                    <p>fermer</p>
                    <a href="#top"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="main-menu">
                    <ul class="navbar">
                        <li><a href="#">Projets</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tower</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <!---------------fin header------------------->
        
         <!---------------début main------------------->

        <main class="main-content">
            <div class="container1">
                <section>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/img-01.jpg" alt="chaises">
                    </figure>
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum at, modi hic possimus quasi tempora sed asperiores qui eius excepturi iure voluptates doloremque minima beatae laboriosam quae ad tenetur esse iste nostrum obcaecati. Quaerat reprehenderit necessitatibus eum cum possimus, a deleniti ipsa nemo corrupti eveniet suscipit repudiandae ipsum pariatur rem earum aspernatur assumenda iste atque officiis ab. Architecto impedit facilis eaque temporibus culpa libero, ut dolorem tempore illo nobis, amet reiciendis consectetur ea velit placeat quia debitis cumque quibusdam. Quibusdam alias praesentium quas enim velit. Illo ab id optio quae sint ex debitis nostrum officia laborum, placeat, illum delectus nesciunt! <a href="#" class="more">Lire la suite</a></p>
                </section>

                <section>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/img-03.jpg" alt="fenetre">
                    </figure>
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum at, modi hic possimus quasi tempora sed asperiores qui eius excepturi iure voluptates doloremque minima beatae laboriosam quae ad tenetur esse iste nostrum obcaecati. Quaerat reprehenderit necessitatibus eum cum possimus, a deleniti ipsa nemo corrupti eveniet suscipit repudiandae ipsum pariatur rem earum aspernatur assumenda iste atque officiis ab. Architecto impedit facilis eaque temporibus culpa libero, ut dolorem tempore illo nobis, amet reiciendis consectetur ea velit placeat quia debitis cumque ! <a href="#" class="more">Lire la suite</a></p>
                </section>
            </div>

            <div class="container2">
                <section>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/img-04.jpg" alt="carreaux">
                    </figure>
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum at, modi hic possimus quasi tempora sed asperiores qui eius excepturi iure voluptates doloremque minima beatae laboriosam quae ad tenetur esse iste nostrum obcaecati. Quaerat reprehenderit necessitatibus eum cum possimus, a deleniti ipsa nemo corrupti eveniet suscipit repudiandae ipsum pariatur rem earum aspernatur assumenda iste atque officiis ab. Architecto impedit facilis eaque temporibus culpa libero, ut dolorem tempore illo nobis, amet reiciendis consectetur ea velit placeat quia debitis cumque quibusdam. Quibusdam alias praesentium quas enim velit. Illo ab id optio quae sint ex debitis nostrum officia laborum, placeat, illum delectus nesciunt! <a href="#" class="more">Lire la suite</a></p>
                </section>

                <section>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/img-02.jpg" alt="velo">
                    </figure>
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum at, modi hic possimus quasi tempora sed asperiores qui eius excepturi iure voluptates doloremque minima beatae laboriosam quae ad tenetur esse iste nostrum obcaecati. Quaerat reprehenderit necessitatibus eum cum possimus, a deleniti ipsa nemo corrupti eveniet suscipit repudiandae ipsum pariatur rem earum aspernatur assumenda iste atque officiis ab. Architecto impedit facilis eaque temporibus culpa libero, ut dolorem tempore illo nobis, amet reiciendis consectetur ea velit placeat quia debitis cumque quibusdam. Quibusdam alias praesentium quas enim velit. Illo ab id optio quae sint ex debitis nostrum officia laborum, placeat, illum delectus nesciunt! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit explicabo eius, ducimus ullam quis blanditiis alias dolor, delectus et officiis. <a href="#" class="more">Lire la suite</a></p>
                </section>

                <section>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/img-05.jpg" alt="artiste">
                    </figure>
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum at, modi hic possimus quasi tempora sed asperiores qui eius excepturi iure voluptates doloremque minima beatae laboriosam quae ad tenetur esse iste nostrum obcaecati. Quaerat reprehenderit necessitatibus eum cum possimus, a deleniti ipsa nemo corrupti eveniet suscipit repudiandae ipsum pariatur rem earum aspernatur assumenda iste atque officiis ab. Architecto impedit facilis eaque temporibus culpa libero, ut dolorem tempore illo nobis, amet reiciendis consectetur ea velit placeat quia debitis cumque quibusdam. Quibusdam alias praesentium quas enim velit. Illo ab id optio quae sint ex debitis nostrum officia laborum, placeat, illum delectus nesciunt! <a href="#" class="more">Lire la suite</a></p>
                </section>
            </div>

            <div class="container3">
                <section>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/img-06.jpg" alt="pneu">
                    </figure>
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum at, modi hic possimus quasi tempora sed asperiores qui eius excepturi iure voluptates doloremque minima beatae laboriosam quae ad tenetur esse iste nostrum obcaecati. Quaerat reprehenderit necessitatibus eum cum possimus, a deleniti ipsa nemo corrupti eveniet suscipit repudiandae ipsum pariatur rem earum aspernatur   <a href="#" class="more">Lire la suite</a></p>
                </section>

                <section>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/img-07.jpg" alt="main">
                    </figure>
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum at, modi hic possimus quasi tempora sed asperiores qui eius excepturi iure voluptates doloremque minima beatae laboriosam quae ad tenetur esse iste nostrum obcaecati. Quaerat reprehenderit necessitatibus eum cum possimus, a deleniti ipsa nemo corrupti eveniet suscipit repudiandae ipsum pariatur rem earum aspernatur assumenda iste atque officiis ab. Architecto impedit facilis eaque temporibus culpa libero, ut dolorem tempore illo nobis, amet reiciendis consectetur ea velit placeat quia debitis cumque quibusdam. Quibusdam alias praesentium quas enim velit. Illo ab id optio quae sint ex debitis nostrum officia laborum, placeat, illum delectus nesciunt! <a href="#" class="more">Lire la suite</a></p>
                </section>

                <section>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/img-08.jpg" alt="oiseaux">
                    </figure>
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum at, modi hic possimus quasi tempora sed asperiores qui eius excepturi iure voluptates doloremque minima beatae laboriosam quae ad tenetur esse iste nostrum obcaecati. Quaerat reprehenderit necessitatibus eum cum possimus, a deleniti ipsa nemo corrupti eveniet suscipit repudiandae ipsum pariatur rem earum aspernatur     <a href="#" class="more">Lire la suite</a></p>
                </section>

                <section>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/img-09.jpg" alt="personne">
                    </figure>
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum at, modi hic possimus quasi tempora sed asperiores qui eius excepturi iure voluptates doloremque minima beatae laboriosam quae ad tenetur esse iste nostrum obcaecati. Quaerat reprehenderit necessitatibus eum cum possimus, a deleniti ipsa nemo corrupti eveniet suscipit repudiandae ipsum pariatur rem earum aspernatur    <a href="#" class="more">Lire la suite</a></p>
                </section>
            </div>
        </main>
        <!-------------------------fin main--------------------------------->

        <!------------------------ début footer------------------------------>
        <footer>
            <div class="form-container">
                <div class="wrapper2">
                    <div class="contact">
                        <h1>Contactez-nous</h1>
                        <form>
                            <p>
                                <label>Name*:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Entrez votre nom" required>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>Telephone*:</label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Laissez votre numero de tel" required>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>Email*:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Votre email" required>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>Message:</label>
                                <textarea name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Laissez-nous votre message"></textarea>
                            </p>
                            <p class="full">
                                <button type="submit">Envoyer</button><br/>
                                <button type="reset">Reset</button>
                            </p>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="responsive">
                <li><a href="#">Responsive Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Principes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Grilles fluides</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Smartphones</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ecran Responsive</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Principes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Grilles fluides</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Medias fluides</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Landscape</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Media querie portrait</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Atelier Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Points de rupture</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Typographie Responsive</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Un formulaire responsive</a></li>
            </ul>
        </footer>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Read about [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this, mobile style first, small screen to bigger,
for example:

```
// mobile style
.navbar li a {
    font-size: 1em;
}
@media (min-width: 560px) {
 .navbar li a {
     font-size: 1.5em;
 }
}
// tablet
@media (min-width: 768px) {
 .navbar li a {
     font-size: 2em;
 }
}
//laptop
@media (min-width: 960px) {
 .navbar li a {
     font-size: 2.5em;
 }
}
//desktop
@media (min-width: 1280px) {
 .navbar li a {
     font-size: 3em;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem is not the navbar, but the contact form , the main and the footer

Comment: just for example: navbar, if you want style change, change "main" or "footer" style different at any next @media(min-width: ... px) { ... }
// mobile style
 footer {
     background: green;
 }
@media (min-width: 560px) {
 footer {
     background: red;
 }
}